# Arraylist data structure

Tags: java, database

This week I am working on data structures and cvs files. I understand how to read a cvs file and I did average for columns from the file but I couldn't do median and mode. My code is just showing the specific column. I want to do median and mode. Can anyone help me how to get the median and the mode from the column I want?

```
"CalforniaSchool.cvs"

school name      students     teachers

C.H.S             1203         45

D.H.S             1023         67

E.H.S             902          34

A.H.S             1280         89
```

```java
ArrayList<String>medianmode=Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("CalforniaSchool.file"));

String []final=medianmode.split(",");


double close = Double.parseDouble(final[2]);//i want to do median and mode for column 2
```

Comment: Do you know final is a reserved word in java??

Comment: That code will not compile. 1) `readAllLines` returns a `List`, not an `ArrayList`. --- 2) Cannot call `split()` on an `ArrayList`. --- 3) `final` is a keyword and cannot be used as a variable name. --- If you *"did average for columns"*, then please **show your working code** for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of functions inside apache common math library, here you are:
[mean](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/Mean.html)

And also some implementations here:

Median:

```
public static int median(int[] m) {
    int middle = m.length/2;
    if (m.length%2 == 1) {
        return m[middle];
    } else {
        return (m[middle-1] + m[middle]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Mode:

```
public static List<Integer> mode(final int[] a) {
    final List<Integer> modes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int max = -1;

    for (final int n : numbers) {
        int count = 0;

        if (countMap.containsKey(n)) {
            count = countMap.get(n) + 1;
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }

        countMap.put(n, count);

        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }

    for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> tuple : countMap.entrySet()) {
        if (tuple.getValue() == max) {
            modes.add(tuple.getKey());
        }
    }

    return modes;
}
```

If you're using python, it would be easier than java with pandas. If you still like to hold on java, I would highly suggest you implement them line by line yourself.

Best.